# How to get rid Memory Leak problem "open_handle_to_dylib_path"

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-leaks

I am getting a memory leak of 128 bytes, in my iPhone App and the responsible caller mentioned in Instruments was "open_handle_to_dylib_path" and the responsible library is "CoreGraphics". So has anybody encountered this problem ?

Thanks and regards,
krishnan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you testing on sim or on device? On device this kind of leaks disappears. Test on device and, if the leak persists, begin to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks Espuz. After I tested in device, I did not have this problem.